# how to send a hole form's attributes with onsubmit()?

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

```
<form method='post' name='...' action='index.html' onsubmit='function(x,z,u)'>
```

I want to send every element of my form that will be sent a PHP file with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","user.php?q="+str,true)
```

What are the proper sintaxes of submitting more than one variables with `Onsubmit()` and the `xmlhttp.open()` ?

I'm self taught, I can double thank you if I can use the code later in the program.

Comment: just append them in your url like `user.php?q1="+str1+"&q2="+str2+"&q3="+str3` But I am sure there are predefined functions somewhere to create that call, so you don't have to do it "manually".

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "user.php?q1="+encodeURIComponent(x)+"&q2="+encodeURIComponent(y)+"&q3="+encodeURIComponent(z), true);
```

It would be easier if you used a library like jQuery. If you want all the inputs from a form, you can use its `$.serialize()` function. If you need to calculate the values to send, it has `$.get` and `$.post` functions that allow you to supply the parameters as an object and it will take care of all the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need AJAX? If you want to send form element to php file, why can't you set it in action attribute?